# Meaning of "sprawling history"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [this](https://edition.cnn.com/style/article/face-visual-odyssey/index.html) article:

> For her **sprawling history** "Face: A Visual Odyssey," designer and author Jessica Helfand assembled a dazzling cabinet of human curiosities

The only definition I found which appears to fit as adjective for *history* is (from [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sprawl)):

> : to spread or develop irregularly or without restraint (a sprawling narrative)

But what does it mean "to develop a narrative without restraints"? Could it maybe describe a history which extensively covers a subject? In greater detail/depth?

In comparison with another sentence from [here](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/04/11/politics/behind-social-distancing-fines/index.html):

> A typical spring afternoon in Brooklyn's **sprawling Prospect Park** brings a crush of joggers, picnickers and frisbee-throwers.

Why was *sprawling* used here? All definitions I found for *sprawl* suggest untidiness, irregularity, ugliness, lack of planning. Does the writer simply meant Prospect Park looks "vast", "to spread in all directions"?

Thanks!

Comment: [Sprawl](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sprawl):  to spread out esp. awkwardly over a large area.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks - So *sprawl* does not necessarily carries negative sense of "awkwardness", "untidiness"?

Comment: @HotLicks But what about the main question (*sprawling history*)?

Comment: It just suggests covering multiple topics in a not rigidly organized fashion.

Comment: See: Urban sprawl, also 'wide-ranging'.